# Squeezing 4K+ Out of H.264?

Tags: ffmpeg, 4k-resolution, timelapse

I'm using FFMpeg to generate perceptually lossless H.264 timelapse videos from still images, where 'lossless' means I'm preserving the 5184 x 3456 resolution of the original photos while gaining the benefits of inter-frame compression for efficient archiving.

H.264 isn't supposed to support 5184 x 3456, but when I choose 4.2.0 (appropriate for my Canon 7D JPEG-compressed images, I believe) it seems to work, except for a couple things:

1. I'm getting warnings I don't fully understand
2. Some players/NLMs don't like the resulting video

My preferred NLMs (e.g., DaVinci Resolve) bog down when playing the clips but otherwise work, which raises the question:  Can I ignore these warnings and carry on?  Or, will I discover some years down the road that my timelapse clips are flawed and no longer usable?  Maybe I should use a different codec (e.g., H.265) instead?

Here's the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -start_number 142 -i IMG_%04d.JPG -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

And here's the output:

```
ffmpeg version N-86482-gbc40674 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 66.100 / 55. 66.100
  libavcodec     57. 99.100 / 57. 99.100
  libavformat    57. 73.100 / 57. 73.100
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 92.100 /  6. 92.100
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Input #0, image2, from 'IMG_%04d.JPG':
  Duration: 00:00:36.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 5184x3456, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 00000000026245e0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] frame MB size (324x216) > level limit (36864)
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] DPB size (16 frames, 1119744 mbs) > level limit (2 frames, 184320 mbs)
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] profile High, level 5.2
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] 264 - core 150 r2833 df79067 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=16 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x133 me=umh subme=10 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=24 chroma_me=1 trellis=2 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=18 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=8 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=2 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=60 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=18.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'recording_studio_construction_20121031_5609.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.73.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 5184x3456, q=-1--1, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.99.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=  884 fps=0.5 q=-1.0 Lsize=  253252kB time=00:00:36.70 bitrate=56516.8kbits/s speed=0.0214x     x
video:253240kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.004778%
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] frame I:4     Avg QP:15.60  size:1304736
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] frame P:178   Avg QP:17.96  size:430397
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] frame B:702   Avg QP:18.48  size:252831
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] consecutive B-frames:  2.6%  2.9%  5.1% 10.0% 19.8% 19.0% 11.9% 22.6%  6.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] mb I  I16..4:  7.5% 86.8%  5.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] mb P  I16..4:  2.1%  4.3%  0.4%  P16..4: 64.4% 13.2% 11.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 3.9%
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.5%  0.0%  B16..8: 46.9% 11.4%  1.5%  direct:12.2%  skip:27.3%  L0:62.1% L1:36.0% BI: 1.9%
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] 8x8 transform intra:68.7% inter:61.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] direct mvs  spatial:99.0% temporal:1.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 69.4% 57.1% 15.4% inter: 29.5% 29.9% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 25% 20% 11% 44%
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  7%  7%  6% 12% 15% 12% 15% 12% 14%
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  6% 12%  3% 12% 15% 12% 14% 11% 15%
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 28% 40% 22% 10%
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:18.0% UV:6.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] ref P L0: 27.0%  4.9% 14.1%  8.7%  7.5%  6.8%  5.9%  3.5%  3.3%  3.1%  2.7%  2.9%  2.7%  2.6%  2.6%  1.8%
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] ref B L0: 30.7% 15.7% 12.0%  7.4%  6.2%  5.5%  4.8%  3.2%  3.0%  2.7%  2.5%  2.3%  2.1%  1.4%  0.4%
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] ref B L1: 85.3% 14.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000000729ae0] kb/s:56322.30
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFmpeg will complain that the resulting bitstream doesn't comply with any level. You can ignore that since ffmpeg, at the least, will decode its output. As will other software players. Hardware players will likely fail.